# Copying local directories to remote hosts with the same directory name

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have three local directories with the following structure:

```sh
$ tree .
|_ inventory
|_ deploy.yml
|_ key
    |_ node1
    |   |_ ...  # several files, like id_rsa.pub etc
    |_ node2 
    |   |_ ...  # several files, like id_rsa.pub etc
    |_ node3 
        |_ ...  # several files, like id_rsa.pub etc
```

My inventory file is down bellow:

```
[remote_cluster]
node1 ansible_host=192.168.100.100
node2 ansible_host=192.168.100.101
node3 ansible_host=192.168.100.102
```

What I want to do is to copy the directory from my local machine to remote machine whose hostname is same with the directory name, for example, copy `node1` to the remote machine named `node1`.  I don't really want to hard-code this feature in that the amount of remote_cluster nodes is not always three. It may increase or decrease in the future.

I have googled some examples, but nove of them fit my goal. And I have made some attempts，but also without success:

```yaml
- hosts: remote_cluster
  name: copy local directories to related nodes
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: copy task
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src:  '{{ item.src }}'
      dest: '{{ item.dest }}'
    with_items:
      - { src: 'key/{{hostvar}}/', dest: '~/.ssh/'}
    tags:
      - copy
```

It seems to me that ansible might be able to identify which remote host is currently executing a task by some variable or something.  But I didn't figure out what the name of this magic variable is.   To make things clear, I'm temporarily replacing that variable name with `hostvar`.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I understood the question correctly, you should replace `hostvar` with `inventory_hostname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking this the wrong way. Your play already loops on each machine in your group. You don't need a loop here (unless you only want a subset of files inside your source dir).

The `copy` module is able to copy an entire tree but will have very poor performance if you have a lot of files. If that's the case, have a look at the [`syncrhonize` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) which is better suited for that.

My feeling is that you are missing a bit of knowledge on internal ansible variables you can use during your play. As a first introduction, I suggest you read [the documentation section on magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables). The one I will use below (as already reported in @JBone comment) is `inventory_hostname`

Here is your fixed playbook (from what I understood and untested). Please note the ending `/` in the `src:` value and read the [corresponding description in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-src)

> If path is a directory, it is copied recursively. In this case, if path ends with "/", only inside contents of that directory are copied to destination. Otherwise, if it does not end with "/", the directory itself with all contents is copied.

```yaml
---
- hosts: remote_cluster
  name: copy local directories to related nodes
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: copy task
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src:  'key/{{ inventory_hostname }}/'
        dest: '~/.ssh/'
      tags:
        - copy
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I want. I will read the document you post up there word by word.